# Why isn't the composition equal to the product?

Tags: graph-theory, permutations, products, function-and-relation-composition

Let $G_1, G_2, H$ be three isomorph graphs. We are given the permutation $\phi:G_1\rightarrow G_2$ with $\phi=(1,2,4,3)$ and the permutation $\psi:G_2\rightarrow H$ with $\psi =(1,2)$. 
In my book there is the following: $$\psi \circ\phi =\phi \cdot \psi :G_1\rightarrow H$$

in order to compute a permuation of $G_1$ to get $H$.

Isn't the composition the same as the product of permutations? Why are the permutations revesed at the product above?

Comment: How does your book define $\cdot$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen There is no definiton of $\cdot$ in my book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different conventions: the product of permutations can be defined either as composition or as composition in the reverse order.  With the second convention, $(1\ 2)\cdot (1\ 2\ 4\ 3)$ means the permuation that is obtained by first doing $(1\ 2)$ and then doing $(1\ 2\ 4\ 3)$ (note that this is the opposite order of usual function composition!).  This is presumably the convention your book uses.